# Procedure to removing square brackets at runtime when string passed as bind

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I have procedure which splits comma separated string.
The string would be passed at runtime in `["",""]` format.

I need to call procedure where string is passed on runtime.

However if i run:

```
begin push_data(100,'q'''||:data);end;
```

It doesn't remove brackets and i need to pass string as `:data`. And this is eactly how i need to call and get results same as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
declare
  v_txt varchar2(4000) := '["Project title afor BYU heads","The values are,\n exactly up to the requirement and analysis done by the team.
Also it is difficult to,\n prepare a scenario notwithstanding the fact it is difficult. This user story is going to be slightly complex however it is up to the team","Active","Disabled","25 tonnes of fuel","www.examplesites.com/html.asp&net;","Apprehension","","","","25","Stable"]';
begin
   push_data(100, substr(v_txt, 2, length(v_txt) - 1));
end;
/
```

Comment: i was thinking something like :declare v_test_proc varchar2(50) :='push_data'; v_sql varchar2(2000); begin v_sql :='begin '||v_test_proc|| '('||:pid||','||'q'''||:data||''');end;'; execute immediate v_sql; end;  but it is taking only the string bind. i want both passed as binds.

Comment: The input string would come from different source. Which is why i want to pass both as binds.

Comment: actually it needs to be used in apex application, so there we are simple calling as : begin push_data(:pid,:data);end; and the string format would be that of array: [""], so need to call/modifiy regex in proc accoridingly. And in dynamic calling brackt are not getting removed.

Comment: Then simply use `substr(data_string, 2, length(data_string) - 1)` in your push_data procedure? Or am I missing something?